# IBM Hyperledger Fabric Running Multiple Nodes on Multiple Datacenters & PCs

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchains, hyperledger

At the moment I'm playing around with some of the Hyperledger Fabric demos that IBM has on their cloud platform Bluemix.

When you initially spool up an instance you're offered more than one option of location, such as `US South`, and... at least one more, I forget, `California` or something.

Running a blockchain application on someone's private cloud somehow feels a bit hollow.

I'd like to know if it's possible at least to have multiple nodes running in multiple IBM datacenters simultaneously maintaining a ledger between eachother and exposing an IP address to demonstrate where they're located.

Is it possible that I could add more nodes to such a network that I can control, i.e. my own machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recent technical steering committee meeting of Hyperledger they discussed the planning for an initiative to connect across multiple cloud providers, to demonstrates that Fabric can be deployed to multiple cloud platforms and integrated into a highly distributed and heterogeneous consortia network.

This effort (as of the time of writing) is under way with a number of community members interested in contributing.

You can read about it more in the meeting minutes [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yyc5eTYjMGjk5dKnmqjG-tg5Tm4-rh5a37YDG40WgYA/edit).